# my query works in SQL but not in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Can someone please advise what I did wrong with the last WHERE clause?

I have the following query that works fine in SQL:

```
with
t1
as
(select ID, state, T, U, R, 
 row_number() over (partition by ID, U order by T asc) as asc_T, 
 row_number() over (partition by ID, U order by T desc) as desc_T
 from rawdata
 where R like ‘%123%’)

 select ID, 
 max(case when desc_T = 1 then state else null end) as state2, 
 max(case when asc_T = 1 then T else null end) as T_0, 
 max(case when desc_T = 1 then T else null end) as T_End, 
 U, R 
 from t1

 group by ID, U, R
 order by ID, U
```

When I plug them in SSRS > Dataset Properties > Query the only difference is that I added an additional line before the last group by:

```
with
t1
as
(select ID, state, T, U, R, 
 row_number() over (partition by ID, U order by T asc) as asc_T, 
 row_number() over (partition by ID, U order by T desc) as desc_T
 from rawdata
 where R like ‘%123%’)

 select ID, 
 max(case when desc_T = 1 then state else null end) as state2, 
 max(case when asc_T = 1 then T else null end) as T_0, 
 max(case when desc_T = 1 then T else null end) as T_End, 
 U, R 
 from t1

 where T > @StartDate and T < @EndDate
 group by ID, U, R
 order by ID, U
```

Query type is text.  I've verified my data source.

I have made 6 field names that are identical to my field sources: ID, U, R, T_0, T_End, State2

My query parameters are @StartDate and @EndDate with values of [@StartDate] and [@EndDate]

But when I run it it's missing a bunch of data and the table looks off.
For instance, it seems that the state column only picks up and first 'max case when', second and third 'max case when' data did not get returned, and i'd get blank T_0 and T_End values for a lot of them where in SQL they all get returned.

I tried to run the query in SSRS without the last WHERE clause and it works just fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo in the question, but the end parenthesis for the definition of `t1` is missing.

Comment: Can you give an example of a row of data that you would expect to be returned by the query, but isn't?   We really can't help diagnose a problem described as "missing a bunch of data".

Comment: Troubleshoot your filtering issues by writing queries.  SSRS complicates the issue.

Comment: @Bridge yes to both questions.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck oops that's just a copy & paste error, i've added it back

Comment: @TabAlleman it seems that the state column only picks up and first 'max case when', second and third 'max case when' data did not get returned, and i'd get blank T_0 and T_End values for a lot of them where in SQL they all get returned.

Comment: @DanBracuk i'm sorry can you please elaborate?

Comment: You can't have added that `WHERE` clause to the end; it must have gone before the `GROUP BY`, or inside of `t1`'s CTE.  Please could you paste in the exact query that exists in SSRS, just to be really specific and eliminate any possible ambiguity or doubt?  My best guess is that you've added it to the outer query, which can mean that the CTE assigns a row the value 1 for `asc_T`, but then your outer query filters that row out.

Comment: To test if it's SSRS *(unlikely)* or your query, try this; run it through SSRS and find an ID where things look wrong.  Run your CTE (the t1) for just that ID, then the whole query for just that ID, then the whole query plus the WHERE clause for just that ID.

Comment: An example of the differences between your query without the WHERE clause, with it in the CTE and with it in the outer query; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2d932/3  I suspect you want the third version, but have the second version?  *(Pay close attention to the values in `asc_T` and `dsc_T` in each case.)*

Comment: @MatBailie i did add it before the group by, i've updated my post to show the exact query in SSRS

Comment: @MatBailie  I followed you advise.  Looks like the last WHERE clause was the issue, with it removed it works just fine

Comment: @MatBailie that was it!  i needed to move the WHERE clause inside the CTE section. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that  @StartDate and @EndDate have the same case as the SSRS variables have. In TSQL case is ignored (@startdate is the same as @StartDate) but not in SSRS. The variables case have to match exactly.

Comment: Their cases do match, I double checked.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue, the WHERE clause needs to be moved inside the CTE section.
Thank you for your help @MatBailie